# MySQL priority queue and packed addons

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

From MySQL 5.7 Source code,

> When sorting using priority queue, we cannot use packed addons.
>   Without PQ, we can try.

Q: Why MySQL 5.7 does not use packed addons during priority queue?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of packing a record is to limit the memory that e.g. an empty `varchar(10000)` uses. But in the worst case (e.g. a varchar using the maximum length), a packed record can actually require more space than an unpacked one.

For the priority queue sort, the memory is allocated at the beginning, and since it has to be able to hold the worst case record, it makes no sense to pack it, so it isn't used. And at that point in the code, it actually *cannot* be used, since the current implementation and the rest of the code expects those records to be, for good reason, unpacked (e.g. the queue allocated less memory than required for worst-case packed records).